# alert message for radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to generate a alert message .When radio button does not select.
Here is my code.

```
<form method=post name="spendform" id="spendform">
<input name="price" type="radio" class="invest-coin-check"  id="pricemethod" >
<button type=submit class="btn btn-lg btn-p-h btn-bw" id="mypayment">Make Investmen
```

t

Here is java-script code

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#mypayment').click(function () {
            if ($('#pricemethod').val() == '') {
                alert('Please Select Payment options');
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.is(':checked')` instead of `.val()`. `.is(':checked')` returns `true` if it is checked, otherwise it returns `false`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mypayment').click(function(){
        if(!$('#pricemethod').is(':checked')){
            alert('Please Select Payment options');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<form method=post name="spendform" id="spendform">
    <input name="price" type="radio" class="invest-coin-check"  id="pricemethod" >
    <button type=submit class="btn btn-lg btn-p-h btn-bw" id="mypayment">Make Investmen</button>
</form>
```

Comment: MH2K9@this code is ruining with both condition. value is empty or checked,working with both

Comment: @sanjayyadav, I'm not clear what do you mean by your comment but the form is only submitted when the radio button is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
$('#mypayment').click(function(){
   if($('#pricemethod').is(':checked')){
      alert('Please Select Payment options');
   }else{
      $('#spendform').submit();
   }
});
```

**.is(':checked') by MH2K9**

Comment: Andy Nopparat @ if($('#pricemethod').val() == '') this is not working. if i used form id then alert box appear.  but not working with field id

Comment: ah true I forgot val();